# backend access rights on a field depending on the user

Tags: api, typo3, global-variables

I use modules to display array in the BE typo3. I know that it is possible to restrict access to the module according to user groups.
I wanted to know if it was possible to restrict the display of a field in my table according to a user group, and how can I do that?

thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, in the user groups access lists tab, you can allow exclude fields for each table - you have to set first the exclude property in TCA.

So the logic is to restrict access to properties in TCA and allow those properties only for specific groups.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-inside/8.7/en-us/CoreArchitecture/AccessControl/AccessControlOptions/Index.html

Another solution is to use TSConfig (Options tab in User Group) and disable some properties like :

```
TCEFORM.pages.title {
   # The title field of the pages table is not editable
   disabled = 1
}
```

See : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 
I use an API to display an array of data in a module. The idea is to use the global variable BE_USER to check if the user is in a particular group to display the table field. I don't really know how to do it and if it is possible, and which table allows to check the groups to which the user belongs